# how to list all files from smallest to biggest

Tags: bash, unix

So I know how to list all files in the current directory from largest to smallest by typing ls -lhS. I just need this list read in the opposite direction by having the smallest file on top and the largest on bottom. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `r` for "reverse order"...

e.g.: `ls -lhSr`